# Powershell regex works for one line, but not another

Tags: android, regex, powershell

I'm running a powershell script to automate my build of my apk for an android project. I can pass in an app version code and name that my build script will use to replace those parameters in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

I have two lines I need to replace. The original lines in the xml file are as follows:

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="Version 1"
```

I'm then running two different commands to replace the text on each line, they are as follows:

```
(Get-Content "$fullOutputPath\$projectFileName\AndroidManifest.xml") | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "(android:versionCode=`")1(`")", "`$1$versionCode`$2"} | Set-Content "$fullOutputPath\$projectFileName\AndroidManifest.xml";
(Get-Content "$fullOutputPath\$projectFileName\AndroidManifest.xml") | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "(android:versionName=`")1\.0(`")", "`$1$versionName`$2"} | Set-Content "$fullOutputPath\$projectFileName\AndroidManifest.xml";
```

To test the parametesr I'm passing in are "2" for the versionCode and "Version 1" for the version name. The resulting xml file comes out like this:

```
$12"
android:versionName="Version 1"
```

So as you can see the second regex replace works just fine, the first one doesn't. I can't seem to understand why or how to fix it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your replace expression to:

```
"`${1}$versionCode`$2"
```

PowerShell replaces the `$versionCode` first before it is handed off to the regex.  The regex sees $12 but there is no 12th capture group.